# DataGridView, BindingSources, DataMembers - I dont understand it

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have `DataGridView`. In database - i have view `vMyView`.

My data grid `DataSource` property is set to `vMyViewBindingSource`.

`vMyViewNameBindingSource` has `DataSource` property set to `mydatabaseDataSet`.

`vMyViewNameBindingSource` has `DataMember` property set to `vMyView`.

I set `DataGridView` source by using "creator" and i don't know where is `DataTable` object.

I know what BindingSouce is for (generally), I was using DataGridViews and other controls with BindingSources successfully, but i never understood it completely.

**1. Can someone explain me what kind of objects can be set as data source for DataGridView? Sometimes its a BindingSource, sometimes something else...**

**2. How I can read data from query/view which is already filled source of data?**

I don't want to run query again, just need fast method to read data which is shown.

Later I want to change this data (not in database, only for display).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question seems to ask alot ot stuff, i will refer you to this code project detailed databinding tutorial. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial